# Creating a custom report to measure how many replies were sent using RMM

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, reply-mail-management

I am trying to figure out how to create a (custom)report where I would be able to track how many subscribers and who (if possible) replies on the emails I have sent. Is it even possible? In tracking and reporting there is no such report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would have to be a custom solution, and on a high level, you could set up something like that:

Set up a sender profile with custom RMM settings and use a Triggered Send for forwards. The email used for the Triggered Send can include a script that you would use to log the email reply into a Data Extension.

> When Reply Mail Management (RMM) is enabled on an account, custom RMM
>   settings can be configured in the sender profile to forward a
>   Triggered Send email to a user or email address, or reply to the
>   Subscriber using a Triggered Send email. This functionality is enabled
>   by checking the ‘Forward using triggered send’ or ‘Reply using
>   triggered send’ options in the sender profile.
>
> Triggered Send emails used for RMM forwarding or replies can contain
>   personalization strings to extract information from the reply email.
>   These personalization strings can be used with AMPscript to customize
>   the email that is forwarded to a user or email address. Additionally,
>   when the ‘Reply using triggered send’ option is used, the Triggered
>   Send email can include information from the Subscribers’ original
>   reply. Use cases for RMM forwarding and replies with Triggered Send
>   emails include:
>
> - Respond with an acknowledgment email to the Subscriber and a formatted abstract of their reply email, explaining they will receive
>     a response in two business days
> - Send the email to an internal email address and include details of the email that the Subscriber replied to (for example, the email name
>     and related journey)
> - Strip the original email from the reply email thread
> - Log the email reply into a Data Extension
> - Create Tasks or Activities in Sales Cloud from the email reply
> - Identify keywords used in the reply message to conditionally trigger other platform actions

Take a look here in the Reply Mail Management Strings section: https://ampscript.guide/system-strings/

Comment: Hello Zuzan, thank you for your opinion on this! I will try it.

Comment: This feedback helped me to create a custom report. It works! Thanks once again! ;)